# pyenv install 2.7.5 - BUILD FAILED - Segmentation Fault - Fedora 29

Tags: python, pyenv, fedora-29

I am trying to install python version 2.7.5 in pyenv, but getting BUILD FAILED error.

However, Working fine for other python versions like 2.7.15 and 3.7.3.

Error:

```
Installing Python-2.7.5...
patching file ./Modules/readline.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 204 (offset -2 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 747 (offset -2 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 857 (offset -2 lines).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 905 (offset -13 lines).
patching file ./Lib/site.py
patching file ./Lib/ssl.py
Hunk #2 succeeded at 430 (offset -5 lines).
patching file ./Modules/_ssl.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 65 (offset -2 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 304 (offset -4 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 1729 (offset -83 lines).

BUILD FAILED (Fedora 29 using python-build 1.2.9-35-gb6109093)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/python-build.20190707202141.31769
Results logged to /tmp/python-build.20190707202141.31769.log

Last 10 log lines:
        Modules/python.o \
        libpython2.7.a -lpthread -ldl  -lutil   -lm  
/usr/bin/ld: libpython2.7.a(posixmodule.o): in function `posix_tmpnam':
/tmp/python-build.20190707202141.31769/Python-2.7.5/./Modules/posixmodule.c:7515: warning: the use of `tmpnam_r' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
/usr/bin/ld: libpython2.7.a(posixmodule.o): in function `posix_tempnam':
/tmp/python-build.20190707202141.31769/Python-2.7.5/./Modules/posixmodule.c:7462: warning: the use of `tempnam' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
./python -E -S -m sysconfig --generate-posix-vars
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
make: *** [Makefile:464: pybuilddir.txt] Segmentation fault (core dumped
```

Same behavior on different machines(both have Fedora 29)

All pre-requisite packages installed as told on [pyenv wiki](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki)